# Modify EXE to stop launching firefox

Tags: firefox, assembly, hex

I'm using a wireless modem program from my ISP. This program automatically disconnect when it detects the line is idle. It does so in 2-5 minutes of idle time. Whenever I reconnect, It will automatically fire up my default browser to the ISP portal. I DID NOT pay them  to shove their web portal in my face 50 times a day. The ISP provides no options for disabling this behavior. Can someone please show me how to hex edit the EXE program to stop it from annoying the hell out of me?

Comment: You could try using a generic (non-branded) program to connect. You only need a few strings (I forgot the names), which are usually fixed per-ISP and not actually per-user.

Comment: I cant find any that works with my ISP. Plus modem settings are not given out to users

Answer (score 1):

If thats the route you want to take then find a free hex editor for your system from : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_hex_editors

And then search for hints. If it's obvious then you may be able to do something. Then again maybe not.

You can also look for programs that specifically deal with this annoyance, for example programs that do a network request every so often to keep the connection active.

Comment: I already have a couple of hex editors, I thought maybe I could modify the assembly instructions that calls the default browser to do nothing instead.

Comment: I think finding a program to periodically keep the connection alive is your best bet. In the days of the dial up modem a common problem was getting disconnected when idle. Search and try some of these utilities.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, try starting the program as another user, and deny this user read/execute access to your default browser's exe file.

Comment: Thanks Dag, I'll try your suggestion if all options fail because I don't want to create another user account just because of one small program.